# Use of ifempty in openTBS docx template

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am trying to use the ifempty attribute in a docx template to choose from 2 available variables. I do not have access to the php files. I am just a user of a system using tbs to allow custom export.

Here are the results of my tests (var.first is empty, var.second contains the word library)

```
[var.first;ifempty=var.second]
```

> Result : var.second

```
[var.first;ifempty=[var.second]]
```

> Result : [var.first;ifempty=library]

How do I get just the content of the second variable if the first one is empty ?
I hope I am being clear. English is not my mother language...

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

Embedded fields are supported only in parameters `file`, `script`, `if`, `then`, `else` or `when`.
See [manual](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_field).

So you cannot used embedded field in parameter `ifempty`,
but you could simply use parameter `if/then/else` instead :

```
[var.first;if '[val]'='';then [var.second]]
```